# React Template w/Identity Server not Working in .NET 6 - Bearer error The issuer is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

When I try to use the .NET 6 React template, I can register users and login. But when I try to hit the "Fetch Data" page I get this error:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://localhost:44449' is invalid"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> ##### SPA template issues with Individual authentication when running in development
>
> The first time SPA apps are run, the authority for the spa proxy might be incorrectly cached which results in the JWT bearer being rejected due to Invalid issuer. The workaround is to just restart the SPA app and the issue will be resolved. If restarting doesn't resolve the problem, another workaround is to specify the authority for your app in Program.cs: builder.Services.Configure("IdentityServerJwtBearer", o => o.Authority = "https://localhost:44416"); where 44416 is the port for the spa proxy.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#aspnet-core